# How to use dynamic query by parameter (native query)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, dynamicquery, nativequery

The code below is part of my repository.
The static function cannot be used as follows, but I want to receive a different query depending on the parameter value taken over by the service.
Can you give me a hand? Thank you in advance.

```
    @Query(value = " select * " +
            "from t_user usr " +
            "left outer join t_sale_order ord on usr.id = ord.user_idx " +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN ( " +
                "SELECT " +
                    "sale_order_idx, sum(taxable_amount) + sum(non_taxable_amount) as amount " +
                "FROM t_sale_receipt " +
                "GROUP BY sale_order_idx " +
            ") receipt " +
            "ON receipt.sale_order_idx = ord.id " +
            "where NOT exists ( " +
                "select 1 from t_encourage_sent_list sl " +
                "where sl.user_idx  = usr.id and sl.push_idx = ?1 " +
            ") " +
            "AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t_user_study us WHERE us.user_idx = usr.id ) " +
//            readBookCondition(readBook) +
            "AND usr.active = 1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> findEncouragePushMsgTarget(Integer pushIdx, Integer readBook);

    static String readBookCondition(Integer readBook) {
        String readBookCondition = "AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t_user_study us WHERE us.user_idx = usr.id ) ";
        if ( readBook != null ) return "";
        if ( readBook != 0 ) readBookCondition.replace("NOT", "");
        return readBookCondition;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write Dynamic queries using JPA Specification.
Refer: [Spring data JPA Specification](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/#Specifications)

Comment: How should I define a query that doesn't change?

Comment: You could not define it by passing the static JPA/SQL query Instead you should invoke the respective methods to construct the JPA query. https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you made a mistake in `if ( readBook != null ) return "";`, it should have been `if ( readBook == null ) return "";` else it will never proceed to next condition `if ( readBook != 0 )...`.

The equivalent of the method `readBookCondition(readBook)` in sql would be:

```
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t_user_study us WHERE us.user_idx = usr.id ) 
-- start of dynamic part
AND
    CASE
        WHEN :readBook IS NULL THEN 
            1 = 1
        ELSE 
            CASE 
                WHEN :readBook != 0 THEN 
                    EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t_user_study us WHERE us.user_idx = usr.id )
                ELSE 
                    NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t_user_study us WHERE us.user_idx = usr.id )     
            END
    END
-- end of dynamic part
AND usr.active = 1;
```

Adjust the above based on the database you are using.